# SASS mixing $str issue

Tags: css, sass, codekit

I'm using sass mixing for creating columns for my grid system. But i'm having a little issue with the output.

This is the my sass function for .col class. As you can see on the screenshot. After i compile the sass file, the compressed css file has too many "///////" slashes.

```css
.col-#{$key} {
  $str: "&";
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
    $str: $str + "," & + "-" + $i + "," + & + "-offset-" + $i;
  }
  @at-root #{$str} {
    @include grid-column;
  }
  & {
    @include grid-column-span(auto);
  }
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
    &-#{$i} {
      @include grid-column-span($i);
    }
    &-offset-#{$i} {
      @include grid-column-offset($i);
    }
  }
}
```

**The css output**
[image]

Do you have any idea how to get rid of these slashes from css?

Thank you!

Comment: Why there `@for $i from 1 through $columns { $str: $str + "," & + "-" + $i + "," + & + "-offset-" + $i;  }` ? It seems to me it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the line `$str: "&";` out of and before the `.col-#{$key}` scope.

Comment: Thank you Sam! Instead of moving the $str: "&"; I've removed $str + after  $str: solved my issue.